# Option to see/edit objects details in ManyToMany field in Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

if we select a foreign key object we get a option to edit that object as shown in image below.
[image]

But there is no edit option or a way to see the objects in many to many field as you can see below.
[image]

Is there any option to open the object in a different object and see it's values?

Answer (score 0):

if you shared your code a bit that would help to edit your code, but I have added one example or a way how you can enable sort of the editing option.

```
class MembershipInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Person.members.through
 
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        MembershipInline,
    ]
    exclude = ('members',)
```

you can also check this https://binary-data.github.io/2015/07/21/django-admin-manytomany-inline-enable-add-edit-buttons/

Comment: But having a lot of inlines like 100 entries will really be hard with this approach and my requirement will have more than 100 entries.